# Unable to change labels position in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

When I draw a component in circuitikz at an angle, I am unable to change the position of label through `l_=label` parameter. However, drawing horizontally or vertically `l_=label` and `l=label` have opposite effect on label placement.

[image: horizontal, vertical and slanted components]

Is this expected behaviour? I want to place diode labels outside the bridge rectifier circuit, but cannot figure out how to do it. I am using MacTeX 2016.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[Do,l=D] (2,0);\draw (4,0) to[Do,l_=D] (6,0);
\draw (8,-1) to[Do,l=D] (8,1);\draw (10,-1) to[Do,l_=D] (10,1);
\end{circuitikz}
\vskip 0.1in
The underscore sign changes label position.
\vskip 0.1in\hrule\vskip 0.1in
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,1) to[Do,l=D] (2,-1);\draw (3,1) to[Do,l_=D] (5,-1);
\draw (6,-1) to[Do,l=D] (8,1);\draw (9,-1) to[Do,l_=D] (11,1);
\end{circuitikz}
\vskip 0.1in
The underscore sign does not change label position.
\vskip 0.1in\hrule\vskip 0.1in
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[R,l=R] (2,0);\draw (4,0) to[R,l_=R] (6,0);
\draw (8,-1) to[R,l=R] (8,1);\draw (10,-1) to[R,l_=R] (10,1);
\end{circuitikz}
\vskip 0.1in
The underscore sign changes label position.
\vskip 0.1in\hrule\vskip 0.1in
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,-1) to[R,l=R] (2,1);\draw (3,-1) to[R,l_=R] (5,1);
\draw (6,1) to[R,l=R] (8,-1);\draw (9,1) to[R,l_=R] (11,-1);
\end{circuitikz}
\vskip 0.1in
The underscore sign does not change label position.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can compile it normally with the desired result, It could be version or compiler matter.

My software details:

```
pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6670 64-bit)
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 3
Circuitikz and Tikz is loaded on the fly by Miktex (without intalling or download)
Means that it uses the latest available version (29/05/2017)
```

RESULT:

[image]